# Is my turtle's shell changing color a bad sign?

Tags: health, reptiles, turtles

My turtle's shell was dark when it was younger and as it has grown, its became lighter is that bad?

Comment: Can you post pictures and tell me about your turtles setup?

Comment: What type of turtle do you have? Also it could be from your water anychance you could show a pic.

Comment: @Sharolyn Washington, everyone on this site is here because they like to help people and answer their questions. You can help them do this by providing as much information as you can. With us not knowing your turtle, we don't have any back ground to help us answer you with anything specific that might help you. Things that would help us are good pictures of your turtle and his setup. Pictures of him when he shell was darker, and lots of info, like how old is he, how old was he when his shell was darker, what do you feed him, how often, when do you clean his enclosure, and similar things.

Answer (score -1):

Could be shedding its [scutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scute), they can turn light during this process.